# Displaying attribute of first element of list in django

Tags: python, django

So I am trying to display the first attribute of the first object of my list in django template. I currently have tried

```
{{objArray.0.name}}
```

and

`{{objArray.0.getName}}`

In my template and

`class ObjInfo():
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
    def getName(self):
        return self.name`

is my class definition. I hard-coded my variables to be declared on any request but I printed it out to be sure it was declared. When I go to the page after running the server, nothing populates. Please help.

*EDIT:* Section of view is like this(from template):

```
<button class="accordion">Obj Info</button>
<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-table">
        <table id="Obj" style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <th>Obj Description</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{objobjArray.0.name}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

There's a few more sections on the table that I ommitted that are static right now, but that is the giist.

Sorry, semi new, here you go:

```
    '''
Created on Jul 9, 2018

@author: packawd
'''

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response,render
from django.template import Context, loader
from django import forms


template_name='App Template.html'

class TicketForm(forms.Form):
    ticketNumber=forms.CharField(label="Ticket number", required=False)
    assetSerial=forms.CharField(label="Asset S/N")
    RadioSerial=forms.CharField(label="Radio S/N")

#Will be used to setup API injection, create object arrays and pass on
#class asassasasasa():
class objInfo():
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
    def getName(self):
        return self.name
def index(request):

    if request.method =="POST":
        form=TicketForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            #Simple check to see if we are pulling data correctly
            """
            print(form.cleaned_data['ticketNumber'])
            print(form.cleaned_data['assetSerial'])
            print(form.cleaned_data['RadioSerial'])
            """
            #Data injection test pt 1
            #obj="engine69420"
            objobj1=objInfo("Engine1")
            objobj2=objInfo("Engine2")

            objobjArray=[]
            objobjArray.append(objobj1)
            objobjArray.append(objobj2)
            #Allows us to use the above fields to call an API or something
            #We need to switch the below to be CAT endpoint and secure the API
            #response = requests.get('http://freegeoip.net/json/%s' % ip_address)
            #geodata = response.json()
    else:
        form=TicketForm()
        objobj1=objInfo("Engine1")
        objobj2=objInfo("Engine2")
        objobjArray=[]
        objobjArray.append(objobj1)
        objobjArray.append(objobj2)
     return render(request, template_name, {'form': form, 'objobjarray':objobjArray,})
```

Comment: Can you share your view?

Comment: This is not the view, this is the *template*.

Comment: How is that context variable being populated? How does your queryset look like?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the name you are using in creating the context `objobjarray` doesn't match the name you are using in your template `ecmobjArray`.

Comment: I am sure that it does match in my code. I wanted to switch it to be more generic for this post. Humor me, what could the issue be if it isn't that? Because I am sure it would throw a fit instead of just displaying nothing.

Answer (score 0):

So what this turned out being is that I was trying to reference `objobjArray` instead of `objobjarray`in my context. It'd probably be handy for me in the future to use the same name for both in this area:

```
'objobjarray':objobjArray
```